# Make change for $4.10 using 40 coins, pennies nickels dimes quarters

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In how many different ways can one make $4.10$ using $40$ coins, all pennies, nickels, dimes, or quarters? (These are US coin names, quarter is 25 cents, dime 10 cents, nickel 5 cents, penny 1 cent, pennies just plural of penny. The 4.10 means same as 410 pennies) It's OK to omit one or more coin types, so equations are
$$q+d+n+p=40,\\ 25q+10d+5n+p=410$$ where there are $q$ quarters, $d$ dimes, $n$ nickes, and $p$ pennies and each of $q,d,n,p$ is to be non negative.

I (believe I) did this and got $30$ ways to do it. My method was rather cumbersome. I'd appreciate it if someone could check this using some kind of software or otherwise.

I'm also interested in any approaches there are to such problems, given several coin values, a specific amount to obtain, and a specific number of coins to use. (More interested in the case(s) when number of coin values is at least $4,$ as in this case.)

Comment: 30 is the correct answer, but I don’t see a simple way to find it directly. I used the following Mathematica expression, which relies on the method of attacking counting problems with generating functions. `Coefficient[
     Series[1/(1 - y x^25) 1/(1 - y x^10) 1/(1 - y x^5) 1/(1 - y x), {x, 
       0, 420}, {y, 0, 40}], x^410 y^40]` For more about this approach, see https://www.google.com/search?q=generating+functions+for+counting or search MSE for “generating functions” and “combinatorics.”

Comment: Steve, Also the number of ways to give back a dollar using dimes, nickels, and quarters.

Comment: @SteveKass Yes, I had thought of exactly this generating function a few weeks ago, but did not know how to extract the coefficients. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, extracting the coefficients in a case like this is typically tedious and involves at least some adding up of cases (or inclusion-exclusion). I don’t know what Mathematica does behind the scenes, but Hagen’s answer is a nice, clever approach that might be as simple as it gets. I would never have thought to attack the problem that way!

Comment: How about phrasing this for people who don't know what are nickles and dimes and pennies?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was just trying to do that and age went down. Try again in a few, maybe think how to word it.

Comment: I would help you, but I don't know the value of these coins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By subtracting,
$$ 24q+9d+4n=370$$
Modulo $4$, we find
$$ d\equiv 2\pmod 4$$
and modulo $3$,
$$ n\equiv 1\pmod 3. $$
Substitute $d=4d'+2$, $n=3n'+1$, and divide by $12$:
$$ 2q+3d'+n'=29.$$
From this modulo $2$, $d'+n'$ is odd.
We also need $q+d+n-3=q+4d'+3n'\le 37$, so
$$ d'+n'=\frac{2(q+4d'+3n')-(2q+3d'+n')}5\le 9.$$
For $(d',n')$, we thus have $10$ possibilities with $d'+n'=9$, $8$ possibilities with $d'+n'=7$, $6$ with $d'+n'=5$ and so on. In total that makes $$10+8+6+4+2=30$$
valid possibilities for $d'$ and $n'$, each determining $q$ and ultimately $p$.

Comment: I also noted, that pennieless solutions give a division by 5 and subtraction route to $4q+2d=42$ which I now realized I solved wrong.

Comment: Likely will accept once I absorb it. I like approach, +1 now.

Answer (score 0):

With $38$ dimes and $1$ nickel  and $1$ quarter you can make $4.10$ dollars with $40$ coins.

I started with $40$ dimes and swapped two coins to compensate for the $10$ cents.

Comment: I think you meant $1$ nickel instead of $1$ penny.  But, more importantly, this is just one way of doing it...the OP seeks to count all the ways of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Of course that is just one solution and finding all solutions require more work.

Comment: too many lulu at least without the coin count limit. 30 ways to give back a dollar using nickels, dimes and quarters at last check. Maximum 20 coins used. minimum 4.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What does the reference in above comment to "max 20,min4" refer to? (couldn't see that, maybe I'm being obtuse...)

Comment: oh, a related problem,  20 nickels down to 4 quarters for the 1 dollar case.